# Observing millions of tiny objects in realtime

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to simulate millions of tiny objects(such as Point) in realtime.

Objects are changing unpredictably, so I had tried applyling Observer pattern by making adaptor class of objects that notify to the observers(I though this way performs faster than checking all objects every time), but then i couldn't allocate enough objects in memory(because every object have a pointer for observer, I think) and performance was very low.

I am using JAVA, so I can't use functions like memcmp().

Is there any solution for this problem?

or please suggest proper approach for me.

Comment: What changes the objects? Is it your program, or is it another program/process that you do not control?

Comment: Does your program also change the objects, or will it only look at them? If you are only looking, you can process things without worrying about order-of-processing (and thus somewhat cheaper); otherwise you will need a sort of event-system to guarantee that changes are processed as they occur.

Comment: You've got a lot of objects.  You're going to need a lot of memory.  I don't know if a particular pattern would be able to help you with this one, since while you describe you're using the observer pattern to deal with unpredictable changes between objects, I don't know if that's entirely the best pattern to use for this situation.  But ultimately, if you're running out of memory, you would likely be better served by throwing more at it.

Comment: What is your definition of "realtime"?

Comment: You could just use a queue or list where you throw in the objects that changed. As you only add a reference of the object to the list, it shouldn't be a large memory overhead.

Comment: Just a side question: isn't this a simulation project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call that huge collection of objects a *pool*. Keep each individual object as light as possible (memory-wise: methods are fine), and minimize copies of objects. Do not use "observer" for each, as it requires adding a "listeners" list to each pool object: allocating and managing a million lists is expensive and slow.

Let us assume that you have a set of *processors* that you wish to call on changed objects. Of course, the processors should know nothing about the pool or finding out what has changed - they only do their one thing.

If changes are **not constant** (only a small fraction of the pool changes during a short span of time), then you could use a producer-consumer architecture to notify processors (code that handles updated pool instances) of pool objects that have changed:

- find out which objects have changed (easy if it is you changing them; scanning the pool in a round-robin fashion may be necessary otherwise). Add references to changed objects to a queue.
- have one or more threads consumer-threads reading from the queue to notify the processors of what has changed where ("chain of responsibility" / "observer"; but you observe the queue, not the list).

There are multiple Java classes (eg.: [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)) intended to simplify exactly this approach.

If changes are **constant** (almost all objects will have changed since they were last processed), then you can avoid the queue entirely, and simply loop constantly over the pool while calling each processor in turn. Do this in an independent thread and sleep a bit after each loop to avoid hogging the CPU and to allow things to change in the pool.

For an example of the latter architecture, see [the Ashley component framework](https://github.com/libgdx/ashley).